# importing dialogflow_v2 causes a distribution not found error in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am importing dialogflowv2 into a chatbot I am working on.
I am using jupyter notebook.
After I run the cell with the import commands, I get a version incompatible error.

I tried updating with *pip install update protobuf*, produced an error saying that versions were incompatible and that it needed v- 4.21.6.
Then I used *pip install --force-reinstall -v protobuff==4.21.6* to update to the exact version it said it needed and now it gives me the following error -
*DistributionNotFound: The 'protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<4.0.0dev,>=3.19.5' distribution was not found and is required by google-api-core*
I also tried opening a new jupyter notebook with no other code than the import commands with all the other modules I am using, it gave me the same result.

How do I resolve this?